# Why Spyder (Python) is killing my internet connection?

Tags: spyder

I´m having problems when using Spyder (Spyder 3.2.6, win 10). When it´s running, the internet connection goes crazy, that is: 90 % of the time it´s down.

I have found some comments online of people with the same problem, but no solutions so far...

Any idea?

Coding without an internet connection, for me, it´s almost impossible. :-(

Comment: Does the internet work when the Windows firewall is turned off?

Comment: Yes @Stephan, it does.

Comment: So Spyder is running, the firewall is turned off, and the internet is still working? If that's really the case, you can probably figure out the rest and post your solution on here as an answer. I don't use Spyder and I don't have Windows 10 myself.